# Cannot parse SOAP XML response in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap

I have got the following XML response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.testingabc.in">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:LoginResponse>
       <return>
           <SessionID>DEMO1234</SessionID>
           <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
           <ResponseMessage>Successful</ResponseMessage>
       </return>
   </ns1:LoginResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have tried

```
            $response = curl_exec($soap_do);
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($response, NULL, NULL,"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
            $soap = $xml->children($ns['SOAP-ENV']);
            $res = $soap->Body->children($ns['ns1']);
            print_r($res);

$response will have the xml response.when I execute this Im getting 

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [LoginResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
```

But now I need to fetch the `SessionID,ResponseCode,ResponseMessage`.How can I fetch it,I need to access the object inside the LoginResponse.

Please help.

Im new to php and finding it difficult to work it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with curl then you need to remove SOAP tags from response to parse as a xml not a good method parse like:-

```
$str ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.testingabc.in">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:LoginResponse>
       <return>
           <SessionID>DEMO1234</SessionID>
           <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
           <ResponseMessage>Successful</ResponseMessage>
       </return>
   </ns1:LoginResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
$szString = str_replace(array('<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.testingabc.in">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:LoginResponse>','</ns1:LoginResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'), '', $str);
print_r(simplexml_load_string($szString));
```

output :-

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [SessionID] => DEMO1234 [ResponseCode] => 0 [ResponseMessage] => Successful )
```

So better to use `SOAP` calling method to get response and parse soap response with soap functions.
For more about SOAP read manual :- http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php